# Error when connecting Apache with Glassfish - Bad request

Tags: apache2, glassfish-3

I am trying to frontend a glassfish server with Apache so that pages requested on port 80 go to the glassfish server for a certain application.I am using mod_jk to do this. When I call my url in the browser the mod_jk.log contains a 'bad request' response from glassfish.

The glassfish server log has the following error

[#|2011-07-10T15:02:39.491+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Error decoding request

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:446)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.decodeAttributes(HandlerRequest.java:501)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.decodeRequest(HandlerRequest.java:451)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:303)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:814)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:743)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:936)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:682)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
|#]

Any ideas on this greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but...

I believe you are hitting a bug in GlassFish 3.1 (and I think it's in 3.1.1 as well) which is described here: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17068. There is a patch in the bug available in report until 3.1.2 is release..